# How to pass a JavaScript variable to DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying a code to pass a javascript variable to the div tag to change its attribute. If anyone knows how to do this, help me.

```
<div id="rate" class="money" data-wpac-chan=""></div>
```

I want to pass a javascript variable to the data-wpac-chan.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var div = document.getElementById("rate").data-wpac-chan = "bal";
</script>
```

It is not working.
I want to replace data-wpac-chan=" " to data-wpac-chan="bal"

Comment: You have to use `.setAttribute("data-wpac-chan", "bal")` instead of `.data-wpac-chan = "bal"`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: roookeee, you should have posted this as an answer. Some guy below copied you and got all the votes instead, haha

Comment: @Gosi didn't copy, thank you very much :/ literally posted it 12 seconds after him :p

Comment: But yes, you probably should have posted it as an answer haha.

Comment: I'll downvote you :D

Comment: can i do this?   var i="bal"; document.getElementById("rate").setAttribute("data-wpac-chan", i);

Comment: Yep, that should work just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
document.getElementById("rate").setAttribute("data-wpac-chan", "bal");
```

SetAtrribute will set any attribute on an HTML element.

Comment: @Gosi I didn't copy it, It's the same one-line answer because its the correct and easiest answer. I posted it less than a minute after him, his comment didn't exist when I started writing the answer. It's really pretty shitty to say someone copied something in a context where there's less than half a minute of difference.

Comment: Wow copy cat gets the correct answer, flagging both of you. Most probably same account.

Comment: @Gosi please do.

Comment: @Gosi Why the sourness? It happens many times that the same solution gets posted as a comment and answer both.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dataset` to assign the value to the attributes that has `data-`. Notice that, you need to use the camelcase as attribute name. So, `wpac-chan` becomes `wpacChan`

```js
document.getElementById("rate").dataset.wpacChan = 'bal'
```

```html
<div id="rate" class="money" data-wpac-chan="">sadasd</div>
```